# Semantic UI radio buttons fields does not work with Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, semantic-ui

I'm having an issue(the databinding does not work) when I tried to integrate angular js with semantic ui, specially if I'm using radio buttons fields like code bellow:

the html

```
   <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <div class="ui form">
            <div class="field">
                <div class="ui radio checkbox">
                   <input type="radio" ng-model="value" value="foo" ng-change="newValue(value)">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <div class="ui radio checkbox">
                   <input type="radio"  ng-model="value" value="boo" ng-change="newValue(value)">
                </div>
            </div>    
         </div>
          {{value}}
    </div>
```

and the controller

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
   $scope.value= 'foo'; 
   $scope.newValue = function(value) {
      console.log(value);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a controller:

`myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function() {});`

then you should place all your logic inside it, otherwise I am not sure that data recycling will work without using `$apply` to collect it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put this line, but it's not working anyway. It works only if i not use the wrapping divs provided by semantic ui. The semantic radiobutton javascript seems not to be compatible with angular js.

Answer (score 0):

You need a directive to have data binding with radio button,
this can be useful [SemanticUI-Angular-checkbox](http://clickermonkey.github.io/SemanticUI-Angular/examples/checkbox/directives.html)